# How to compare generic parameter type with another specific type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method in my Android app using Java. How in the method body I can check that the generic parameter is of a given type? I want to do something like following:

```
public <T> T readSomething() {
   if (T == String.class) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: The type parameter? Impossible, and that is by design. But if you pass in a variable that is type T, that is possible. If that is acceptable, I can type up an answer for you.

Comment: "Type erasure" ensures that types are only available before compilation. Thus, your "T" is not available when running the code.

Comment: What about *this.getClass() == String.class* ?

Comment: @GyroGearloose *What about this.getClass() == String.class ?* -- This will not work unless you have an instance of `T` sitting around. If `this` is an instance of `T`, then yes, that might work. But if that was true, you should already know the answer to that question, and it wouldn't make much sense to ask it. It would be like asking myself "***Hello me - what is your name?***" I already know my name.

Comment: More specifically, how does _T_ apply to the _method_.  You may be able to _[bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)_ _T_.

Comment: @davidalayachew Yes, T might be available *indirectly*, not by design  but haphazardly because when some type T is used, there is a fair chance that some object of that calss is hanging around somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to erasure, the only way is to pass a type token:

```
public <T> T readSomething(Class<T> clazz) {
   if (clazz == String.class) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely another way to do it. Arguably the most convenient way, but not always possible. Where do I go to look up information about type tokens? Google is not being very helpful.

Comment: hm... so I need to change the signature of my method to accept that parameter, It's not ideal, but it's doable. Is that the only `convenient` way?

Comment: I'm afraid so. Unless you have a reference to an object that is an instance of the type, in which case you could inspect that.